# How to get value of table instead of Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net project where try to get data from asp:repeater. In This moment I get value using `<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>`, but I need instead of `Company.CategoryId` get `Company.Category.CategoryId`, how can I do this in asp.net? In MVC I'm using `DisplayFor(x => x.Company.Category.CategoryId)`, does here have smth similar?

This is the next part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193852/how-to-display-value-in-asprepeater

Comment: If possible then can you please provide your code?

Comment: sharing your code and example will help you!

Comment: @JayeshGoyani look at in the link of prev question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can evaluates object properties like below,

```
<%# ((Company)(Container.DataItem)).Category.CategoryId %>
```

Comment: But, can you help me, if I have for example Company.Locations (M:N) relationships, how can I display Locations?

Comment: do you mean in repeater you want to display locations ? it is how you bind data control.

Comment: Yes in repeater for example add one more column Locations

Comment: What did you try for that. assuming your existing datasource contains location object/values. If you can upvote my answer, please do as which authenticates the solution. thanks